# How to check returntype in Spring Unittest using MockMVC?

Tags: spring, unit-testing, mockmvc

The Spring method I wanna test

```
@RequestMapping(value="/files", method=RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public List<FileListRequest> get() {
   return getMainController().getAllFiles();
}
```

I want to be assured all calls to /files are responded with an List[FileListRequest]. How?
This is the method in which the test is supposed to be.

```
@Test
public void testGetAll() throws Exception {
    this.mockMvc.perform(get("/files").accept("application/json"))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(content().contentType(SOMETHING);
}
```

Can I simply replace the SOMETHING or am I totally wrong?

Can I run assert methods on the object returned by perform()?

Comment: you could use `json path`  to test if  the response contains the specific data

Answer (score 3):

**Edit:**

```
MvcResult result =   this.mockMvc.perform(get("/files").accept("application/json"))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
             .andReturn();

String content = result.getResponse().getContentAsString();
```

// Convert json String to Respective object by using Gson or Jackson

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
TypeFactory typeFactory=objectMapper.getTypeFactory();
List<SomeClass> someClassList =mapper.readValue(content , typeFactory.constructCollectionType(List.class, SomeClass.class));
```

//Assert here with your list

---

You could use [Json Path](https://github.com/jayway/JsonPath)  to check if specific data exist in your response

a code snipper from by old project

```
mockMvc.perform(get("/rest/blogs")) .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.blogs[*].title",
                        hasItems(endsWith("Title A"), endsWith("Title B"))))
                .andExpect(status().isOk());
```

Comment: Is there I way I can work directly with the expected return object, in this case the List?

Comment: @John Yes.. I will update answer with edit but it is not recommended to test rest response like this.

Comment: Ok. There is only 1 thing I need to check: is the return type the expected return type (Is there a list returned, ...). What the exact content of the returned object is doesn't matter at this moment.

Comment: @John check my edit. Haven't tried but hope it will wrk

Comment: Okay! What is the reason a simple type check is so complex to do with MockMVC?

Comment: @John I am not sure because I have never tried checking return type for the response. There might be a way, I request you to please wait for more answers

Answer (score 1):

1. You cannot use `contentType` to check the class of instances. The `Content-Type` is to determine the format of text sent/returned in a HTTP(S) request/response, and has nothing to do with programmatic type-check. It only regulates that the request/response is in `json`/`text-plain`/`xml`, etc.
2. To check the type of the objects returned in the response, let's assume that the response is in format JSON(built-in Jackson in Spring boot will do the (un)marshalling), and we just use `org.hamcrest.Matchers.instanceOf(Class<?> type)` to check the class of first item in the list, with `jsonPath`.

A working snippet:

```
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.instanceOf;

...

@Test
public void testBinInfoControllerInsertBIN() throws Exception {
    when(this.repository.save(mockBinInfo)).thenReturn(mockBinInfo);

    this.mockMvc.perform(post("/insert")
            .content("{\"id\":\"42\", \"bin\":\"touhou\", \"json_full\":\"{is_json:true}\", \"createAt\":\"18/08/2018\"}")
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
            )
        .andExpect(content().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE))
        .andExpect(status().isCreated())
        .andExpect(jsonPath("$[0]", instanceOf(BinInfo.class)))
        .andExpect(jsonPath("$[0].bin", is("touhou")));


}
```

If you want to check every item in the list... maybe it is redundant? I haven't seen code examining each and every item in the list because you have to iterate. There is way, of course.